# Player player doesnt work (Minecraft Java Dev)

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm writing the core plugin for my Minecraft server and I was implementing the PlayerJoin and Player leave functions when I came across this issue.

When I try to compile or package it says this:

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'org.bukkit.entity.Player'
```

And I don't know what to do with it.

Heres the code:

```
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.player.PlayerJoinEvent;

public class PlayerJoin implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
        Player player = e.getPlayer().getDisplayName();
        e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[+] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Welcome back adventurer! You may now continue your quest " + ChatColor.GREEN + player.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `e.getPlayer()` method already return the player. You are using the `getDisplayName()` too early, and you just should remove it such as you invoke it when changing the join message.

The method `getDisplayName()` return a string, which can't be changed to Player. That's why you get this issue.

To conclude, you will have this code:

```java
public class PlayerJoin implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    void onPlayerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent e){
        Player player = e.getPlayer();
        e.setJoinMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "[+] " + ChatColor.GRAY + "Welcome back adventurer! You may now continue your quest " + ChatColor.GREEN + player.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```